# Tag friends in published Photo stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This [article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads) is very nice for publish photo stories. 
But... How can i tag my friends?

i've tried much examples... but all fails

e.g. in explorer tools

/mee/feed

```
message: "test tag multiple photo"
attached_media[0]: {"media_fbid":"13936770212321"}
attached_media[1]: {"media_fbid":"32312313213113"}
tags[0]: {"tag_uid": "12345222226", "x": 0, "y": 0}
```

or i try after post photo and get id

/13936770212321/tags

```
tags: 12345222226
```

but 
nothing... help!

Comment: Are your friends in the photos? Did the user select their friends?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
SOLVED !

I check the id friend with command

```
me/friends/
```

and the correct request /me/feed is:

```
message: "test tag multiple photo"
attached_media[0]: {"media_fbid":"13936770212321"}
attached_media[1]: {"media_fbid":"32312313213113"}
tags[0]: 1234567890
```

the tags must be integer